# Del key in AIX ksh over PuTTY telnet

Tags: terminal, ksh, aix, putty, key-mapping

At the place where I work we're developing under AIX with ksh and connecting to it via `telnet`. Most people use ArcTel to connect, while I prefer PuTTY. The only problem I have with PuTTY is that the <kbd>Del</kbd> key isn't working - it prints `[3~` instead. The funny thing is that in ArcTel it *is* functioning correctly.

I tried looking at the ArcTel settings and there it only has one switch, called "Backspace and Delete": it can be either "normal" or "VNS-style". I have normal turned on (and Del works as expected). In PuTTY I tried playing around with the keyboard settings and couldn't find a combination that'd make <kbd>Del</kbd> do what I want it to do.

Is there a way to make this work in PuTTY? Maybe remapping the `[3~` character in my `.profile`? I don't want to switch from Vi-mode in KSH though.

Answer (score 1):

I use putty without any problem connecting to AIX. My .profile has

```
stty erase ^?
```

and my putty settings have Terminal-keyboard "The Backspace key" checked in Control-? (127)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if AIX's ksh supports custom key bindings. I can't find them documented in the AIX manuals, but I think it's a [standard ksh feature](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch10_03.htm). Try setting up a binding for `\e[3~` (where `\e` is the escape character). If that works, you can set up bindings for other key combinations as well.

```
KEYBD_handler () {
  case ${.sh.edchar} in
    $'\e[3~') .sh.edchar=$'\004';;
  esac
}
trap KEYBD_handler KEYBD
```

(`$'\004'`, i.e. `Ctrl+D`, is the stadndard [binding](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.baseadmn%2Fdoc%2Fbaseadmndita%2Fkorn_shell_emacs_edit.htm) to delete the next character.)

It may be possible to fix this by changing your terminal definition in [terminfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo). I don't know how to do this in AIX.

On a related note, you may need to either configure PuTTY to [send the right character for <kbd>Backspace</kbd>](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-backspace), or run `stty erase '^?'` or `stty erase '^h'` as appropriate on the AIX machine, or change the terminfo definition to match.

Comment: Didn't help in my case, I tried putting that in my .profile, ksh didn't have anything against it, but Del still does the same thing it did before.

I didn't know about the Ctrl+D shortcut though, thanks.

Comment: @AntonZujev Is that ksh or ksh93? By the way, if you have the option to use bash or zsh, they are a lot better at interactive use than ksh.

Comment: Didn't see the comment before, sorry. How do I find out if it's ksh or ksh93? And I'm afraid we can't change shells here.

Comment: @AntonZujev `echo ${KSH_VERSION}` or `echo ${.sh.version}`

Comment: The first command returns a blank line and the seconds gives me "ksh: ${.sh.version}: bad substitution". Any other way?

EDIT: Found that I could do it with ESC, then ^V. Got back "Version M-11/16/88f".

Comment: @AntonZujev I think that means ksh88. It looks like AIX's ksh is a rather underfeatured version. There may be no way to achieve the workflow you need, I'm afraid changing terminals or shells may be your only option.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I feared it was. Guess I'll have to learn to work with what I have.